# Flexbox/Float anchor items to top

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-float

Consider this example:
[image]

Notice that that 4th item is pushed to top instead of aligning with the 3rd item. I can't achieve this using flexbox's `align-items: flex-end`, neither with floats.

I am aware of achieving this by using masonry/isotope, but I would like to avoid using javascript just for this layout.

Is it possible to achieve using only CSS?

Comment: Do you need IE/Edge support?

Comment: i think you added separate row but did't add flex to that rows - https://jsfiddle.net/ouu6kh61/ , if added flex to rows https://jsfiddle.net/ouu6kh61/1/

Comment: Their is pretty much only 2 ways, using Flexbox, where you either give the parent a height or wrap them in 2 columns: https://jsfiddle.net/d0z0p76q/ ... And using a wrapper, you don't even need Flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/rxxommjg/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible via [CSS Grid Layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px 30px;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

/* styles just for demo */
.grid__item {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.b, .d {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.a {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  /* setting height just for demo */
  height: 200px;
}

.b {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.c {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.d {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item a">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item b">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item c">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item d">4</div>
</div>
```

If you need IE\Edge support you should use old grid syntax. You can fake `grid-gap` using additional grid columns and rows. Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 30px 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 30px 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: auto 10px 1fr 10px auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto 10px 1fr 10px auto;
}

/* styles just for demo */
.grid__item {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.b, .d {
  -ms-grid-row-align: start;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.a {
  -ms-grid-row-span: 3;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
  /* setting height just for demo */ 
  height: 200px;
}

.b {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.c {
  -ms-grid-row: 5;
  grid-row: 5;
}

.d {
  -ms-grid-column: 3;
  grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item a">1</div>
  <div class="grid__item b">2</div>
  <div class="grid__item c">3</div>
  <div class="grid__item d">4</div>
</div>
```